# HTTPError when appending DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, try-except, http-error

I am reading Python code from another programmer, particularly the following code block:

```py
try:
    df.append(df_extension)
except HTTPError as e:
    if ("No data could be loaded!" in str(e)):
        print("No data could be loaded. Error was caught.")
    else:
        raise
```

In this, `df` and `df_extension` are `pandas.DataFrame`s.

I wonder how an `HTTPError` could occur with `pandas.DataFrame.append`. At least from [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) I can not find out how `append` raises an `HTTPError`.
Any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: Are you saying that an Exception **is** occurring and that either your *print* or *raise* statements are being executed?

Comment: It won't occur, unless `df.append` was for some reason previously assigned to a callable that might raise that error... `git grep` on pandas repository mentions `HTTPError` in io/xml parts only...

Comment: @JCaesar No, the exception is not occuring. My question comes because I am confused when it should ever occur.

Comment: @Neither I can assure quite certainly that the method `pandas.DataFrame.append` (or, more precisely, this name) is not modified (more precisely: assigned) to something else.

Comment: I don't think it can occur if both *df* and *df_extension* are unmodified Pandas dataframes. Perhaps the original author had other code where you now have the append() which *could* have raised that Exception

Comment: Okay, then; if `df.append` specifically is also safe, you can rest assured :) Code is inappropriate. Is it open source, though?

Comment: JCaesar, Neither: Alright. This is also what I thought. Thank you for having a look at it and sharing your guess.
Feel free to make it an answer (one of you); otherwise I will do so later.

Comment: @Neither No, it's not open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments to the question by @JCaesar and @Neither, you don't have to worry about an `HTTPError` arising from the use of `df.append`. The `try`-`except`-block does not seem to have any justification. The one-liner

```py
df.append(df_extension)
```

suffices.